# ¿Cómo deshabilitar botones después de presionarlos?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo un JsGrid, lo que pretendo lograr es deshabilitar los botones después de ejecutar la acción,(o al menos lograr que al dar clic sobre la fila ésta se deshabilite).

Les dejo mi código. Si alguien pudiera ayudarme se lo agradecería mucho.

HTML

```
           <form class="form-group">
                <div id="div_prueba" style="width: 60%; overflow: auto; margin: 0 auto;">
                    <div id="table_div"></div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Aquí mi función

```
      $("#table_div").jsGrid({

        width: "100%",
        height: "auto",
        paging: true,
        center: true,
        autoload: true,
        filtering: false,
        confirmDeleting: false,
        pageSize: 15,
        editing: true,
        reload: 20,

        rowClick: function (args) {
            //Sobre esta función intento hacer la prueba, con éstas lineas no me está funcionando.
            //$(this).removeProp("disabled", true);
           // var x = $(this).attr('class');
            //alert(x);
             $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
             $(this).prop('disabled', true);

        },

        fields: [
            { name: "Columna1", title: 'Columna1', type: "text", width: 40, align: "center", editing:false },
            { name: "Columna2", title: 'Columna2', type: "text", width: 40, align: "center", editing: false },

        //Estos botones requiero deshabilitar
             {
                 type: "control", deleteButton: true, deleteButtonTooltip: "Rechazar", deleteButtonId: "btnRechazar",deleteButtonClass: "jsgrid-button jsgrid-cancel-edit-button",
                 editButtonClass: "jsgrid-button jsgrid-update-button", editButtonId: "btnAceptar", editButtonTooltip: "Aceptar", width: 35

             }
        ]

    });
```

Inspeccionando con mozilla no genera ningún id o name para identificar cada fila y elementos generados, aquí mi complicación. Gracias anticipadas.

Comment: lo que puedes hacer es deshabilitar los inputs dentro del row, solo que al recargar el grid, volverían a estar activos

Comment: puedes agregar el html, para ver qué es **#table_div**

Comment: @ReneLimon ya lo anidé, gracias

Answer (score 1):

Intenta cancelando directamente en el objeto dentro de la función o evento que requieres:

```
$("#table_div").jsGrid("option", "editing", false);
```

O al campo en especifico:

```
$("#table_div").jsGrid("fieldOption", "Control", "visible", false);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @jsanchezs, lamentablemente esas líneas no me funcionan :(

Comment: @masha10 Te general algun error?, o simplemente no ocurre nada?, es curioso pues es la manera incluso que tiene la documentación oficial del plug.

Comment: simplemente no hace nada @jsanchezs

Comment: Revisaste en el inspector del navegador que error da en la consola ?, algo debe estar mostrando alli que sea la razón del fallo, aqui me funciona bien.